# Error INVALID_EMAIL when authenticatiing with Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

for some reason when you sign up the error Becomes INVALID_EMAIL. but first of all the email i entered is valid, second of all the email goes in my firebase auth as one of the users of my site. Help would be appreciated , Thankyou.

The code was a lot so i just made a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zv6j0CseOo0QtrqQyS9Y?p=preview) so you guys can see it.

Here is my index.html(i must submit at least one code if i have a plunker link):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.6.2/firebase-simple-login.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.3/angularfire.js"></script>
    <script src = "http://s.codepen.io/assets/libs/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="X-UA-Compatible" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <title>Login - UniqueCoders</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="LoginApp">
    <div id="page">
        <header class="container">
        </header>
        <div ng-view>
        <main class="container">
            <div class="row login">

                <form>
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model = "email" id="email">
                    <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Password" id="password">
                    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" ng-click="createUser()">
                </form>
                <a href = "#/logIn">Want to Log In?</a>
            </div>
        </main>
        </div>
        <footer class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <small>&copy; 2016. Unique Coders</small>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Linking to a plunkr is not enough. Include the *minimum* code to reproduce the error in your question. The HTML itself is likely (but I may be wrong here) the least important. Try reducing the problem to just a bit of code that calls `Auth.$createUser()` with hard-coded values. If that also fails, you only need to share that code. If that doesn't fail, you know the problem is in how you get the values from the HTML. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Wait what am i suppose to test again? I dont understand @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Nvm @FrankvanPuffelen i hardcoded the value of email and it still fails... :(  What do i do now

Comment: I still need help @FrankvanPuffelen... Anyone Please help me. Im getting very lost with this. Thankyou

Comment: The plunkr now creates users without problems.